# How to add wpf controls in the ribbon? My project is vsto excel c# workbook

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, vsto

How to add wpf controls in the ribbon? My project is vsto excel c# workbook.

This is part of code I have for my ribbon, but how can I insert a wpf control in there?
Am I limited to place stuff on the ribbon only from the given ones, the ones
that show up with intellisense?

```
  <tab id ="TabMy" label="MyTab">
    <group id="GroupMy" label="MyGroup">
        How do I insert wpf control here?
    </group>
  </tab>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add WPF controls to the Ribbon, only the supplied Ribbon items.